# What layers to use when comparing 2 arrays of 2 image

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I have 2 arrays of image, one of a degraded picture, the other one of the same picture but in a clean state. Their `shape=(576, 720, 3)`, since these images are `720*576`, and have `3` channels (RGB). I am currently trying to train my model with the degraded picture array as input, and the clean picture array as output. It is working perfectly fine, however I do precisely know what layer to add to my model, nor how to improve the accuracy I currently have.

Here's my current model ( which is **NOT** good, I basically just randomly put layers here ):

```py
model = models.Sequential()

model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, 5, activation='relu', padding='same', input_shape=(576, 720, 3)))
model.add(layers.AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))

model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, 3, activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(layers.AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(layers.Conv2D(3, 3, activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(layers.UpSampling2D((4, 4)))
```

[image: Model Description]

And here's how I compile it:

```py
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='mean_absolute_error', metrics=["accuracy"])
```

I currently have a 5000 pair of degraded / clean image, and I manage to get to ~75% accuracy and ~20 loss, but can't get to improve the model.

What I would like is to understand what I am doing here, since I can't get to find anything on the Internet apart from Image Classification, which is not what I am doing. I would like to know what layer can be useful, and why. I know Conv2D is useful since I want to find flaws in images and correct them, and I know LSTM is useful if I'm working with a video, but apart from that, I do not know the correct layer Sequence to setup, nor the correct layers.

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You can try some famous pixel2pixel models out there, like U-nets.

Comment: I have seen many using generative models such as autoencoders for removing noise from images. It works by first downsampling the image using conv layers and then upsampling using conv-transpose. In case of comparing two images many suggests siamese networks as a good choise.  It has two identical feature extraction layers in parallel accepting images to check and a loss layer to determine the similarity of the features extracted. There are many other methods also.

Answer (score 0):

I had a project similar to this one.
As @meowongac stated in his comment, **Unet** was showing pretty good results and is easy to build.

Look at [this repo](https://github.com/zhixuhao/unet) to implement it. Note that there are prettier way to write it, especially if you want to make the number of filters/number of conv blocks as parameters. If you want to have understanding on why the Unet is good in your case read [its paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.04597). Briefly, it uses a path to get small features on an contracting path, then a expansing path to get the spatializaion.

On my project Unet was working well but I wanted a better model, I came across [the DenseUNET repo](https://github.com/xmengli999/H-DenseUNet/blob/master/denseunet.py) that add Dense layers to outperform Unet, and it was the case.

Edit: I also tried [segnet](https://github.com/ykamikawa/tf-keras-SegNet) that was showing good results but not as good as Unet, it's even easier to implement.

Also you **souldn't** look at **accuracy** since you're using regression paradigm. It's only useful in classification with probability between 0 and 1